# The error :ava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 9 out of bounds for length 9 ? #java

Tags: java

the code:
Find the frequency of elements in an array::

```
int array=-1;
int arr[]=new int[] {101,88,3,65,6,3,0,0,88};
int arr2[]=new int[arr.length];
int count=0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (int j = i + 1; i < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
      count++;
      arr2[i] = array;
    }
  }
  if (arr[i] != array) {
    arr[i] = count;

  }
}
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] != array) {
    System.out.println("Count of  " + arr[i] + " = " + arr2[i]);
  }
}
```

**your The error :ava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 9 out of bounds for length 9 ?? #java**

Could you Plz help me >>
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your inner loop increments `j` but has a condition based on `i`. Change it to `j` and you should be OK:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        // Here -------^
```